# Adding yum .repo to install RPM breaks build; other ways to install RPM? "HTTPS Error 404 - Not found"

Tags: linux, http, rpm, yum, rhel

I am trying to add a `.repo` file to the yum repository at `/etc/yum.repos.d` so I can point to a repo we have at Jfrog artifactory (artifactory.OurWebsite.com/artifactory/...) that has some RPMs that I need.

I am adding this `.repo` file inside a build script, `./build.sh` in a repository we have that basically "builds" up a Red Hat Enterprise Linux OS on a **OVF** file, that we later install and run as a VirtualMachine (VM) on a Server running a VMWare ESXi (Can manage/hosts multiple VirtualMachines).

We have the build script working. It calls some other artifactory RPMs that it is pointed to, and uses `yum install` to install their RPMS. I even copied the code structure for the one I am trying to add. There is a section where it `cats` in some artifactories with this structure:

```
cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/csr.repo <<'CAT'

[Artifactory]
name=Artifactory
username=
password=
baseurl=https://artifactory.OurWebsite.com/artifactory/virtualrepo/PathToRepoData
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1

[Artifactory2]
name=Artifactory2
username=
password=
baseurl=https://artifactory.websitename.com/artifactory/repo2/PathToRepoData2
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
CAT

yum install -y name-of-rpm1 name-of-rpm2 ...
```

Everytime I add the REPO in question, that I am trying to add, it breaks the entire build process because when `yum install` is called, it returns:

```
failure: repodata/repod.xml from Artifactory1: [Errno 256] No more mirros to try
https://artifactory.OurWebsite.com/artifactory/virtualrepo/PathToRepoData/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not found
```

Another engineer told me it could be related to a DNS issue where we can't reach this artifactory behind our firewall, and thus it cannot resolve the FQDN of the artifactory...

...But I am running in a Sandbox environment where there "should" be no firewall issues...can anyone please help? Could it be my `baseurl` path? I think I am pointing to not a normal artifactory repo but a "virtual repo"......

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is more appropriate to ask on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is clearly not a DNS issue: 404 means the remote server has been reached, but it could not find the resource yum requested. Looks very much like `baseurl` is off. Try to contact whoever is providing that repo. Chances are it has moved.

Comment: @DaSourcer thank you. It actually looked like I need to point to the dir that has the /repodata/repomd.xml file, and it couldn't find it at that baseurl, thus it was returning 404  - not found..... Somehow all the Senior Engineers who were "helping" me , didn't spot this, didn't know, or simply didn't GAF apparently smh....

Comment: There, there. It is simple to assume incompetence, malice, and/or indifference. Truth is, even experts do suffer from tunnel vision from time to time. If they are locked in one problem domain, they can easily turn blind to the obvious. Try not to get bitter ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because my `baseurl` was wrong. It needed to point to the directory that contained the `repomd.xml` file, which is meta data created for the repo. It ended up being located at :

`baseurl=https://artifactory.websitename.com/artifactory/`

because it looks like it automatically appended `repodata` to the baseurl, and it was looking for the `repomd.xml` file so the final string was like:
`baseurl=https://artifactory.websitename.com/artifactory/repodata/repomd.xml`

and this is what worked